# Windows 8.1 JavaScript App Http Windows Authentication

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-authentication, windows-8.1

I am trying to build a metro style line of business app using JavaScript.  This app is targeted at enterprise users inside my company firewall - no internet connection.

The app itself will run in Kiosk mode, running as a low-privilege account.  I have figured out the CredentialPicker for asking the user for credentials.  Now I would like to call an existing WebAPI REST service that is secured with Windows Integrated Authentication on a company server.

How can I make the request using the credential I receive from the CredentialPicker?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I may have a lead...if I turn off Enterprise Authentication in the appxmanifest, supposedly the system will launch the CredentialPicker itself similar to a browser challenge box, so I'm going to try that.  Got this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664120/windows-store-app-with-enterpriseauthentication-and-impersonation